# Are questions uniquely about Sakurai relevant to this site?

Tags: discussion

There’s a quick question [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/32974/gyromagnetic-ratio-of-the-electron/32975?noredirect=1#comment43512_32975) that has at least one upvote at the time of writing, and has an on-point answer, but I struggle to see the relevance of the question to quantum computing.

The question is uniquely about Sakurai’s definition of the gyromagnetic ratio and where the speed of light $c$ comes in. I’m trying to be favorable and not dismiss it yet, as there were some other well-received questions here and on MathOverflow about the relevance (or rather, the lack of relevance of) of $\hbar$ to quantum computing, so questions of units and fundamental constants aren’t completely off-topic.

But, Sakurai is a standard textbook for quantum *mechanics* and not so much quantum, or really anything, computing.

Is this an edge case that we should live with, given that it was quickly and properly answered?

Comment: What do you think of this: https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/281/2293 ?

Comment: Thanks! Although I am one of the eight +1s apparently for that question, now I’m not so sure about it tbqh. I wouldn’t want this site to turn into the theoretical computing site, as there’s already a stack for that (although it gets much less volume than we do). I don’t think a question uniquely about Arora and Barack, or Knuth, are relevant for this site.

Comment: I think it should really depend on whether the question is framed from an informational perspective or not. If it asks about the underlying physics, as Sakurai-like questions (and generally questions arising from standard textbooks introducing quantum mechanics) will tend to be, it's much better asked on physics.SE, which will have plenty of related questions and a more receptive public already. If it asks about more "informational aspects" (eg bra-ket formalism, more general questions about entanglement or coherent or superposition, etc) then it's fine here

Comment: also, regarding the related post: I agree that questions about "quantum foundations" are fine, but "quantum foundations" is a very specific line of research within quantum information, and I certainly wouldn't label questions about basic quantum mechanics as questions about "quantum foundations".